# How to send push notification in iOS 10 via FCM(Firebase) or by native?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app which has deployment target iOS 7.1. I am using Firebase for the push notifications. Push notifications working fine in the iOS 9 devices. But not working in the iOS 10 devices.

When I searched, I found this note [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client).

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
  UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
  (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
  UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
  [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
} else {
  // iOS 10 or later
  #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
  UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
      UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
      | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
      | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
      requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
      completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
      }
   ];

  // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
  // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
  [[FIRMessaging messaging] setRemoteMessageDelegate:self];
  #endif
}
```

And this note:

> Important: for devices running iOS 10 and above, you must assign your delegate object to the UNUserNotificationCenter object to receive display notifications.

Is it necessary to send push notification via this method (which is a new class `UNUserNotificationCenter`)? is it be possible through the old push notification registration methods?

Please let me know. Because of this, I need to update my project to the Swift version 2.3 or 3.0, and it will take time.

Comment: Yes it'll take time and you need to update the above methods listed on https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client. It is due to introduction of UserNotifications in iOS 10.

Comment: @iOSCuriosity thanks for replying.

Comment: @iOSCuriosity  I have the same problem. My app is ready to  release appstore. Now i dont have enough time to change my app to swift 3. Is there any solution for receiving push notifications in ios10 devices without updating xcode and swift?

Comment: @GaneshKumar The only way i know to solve this is by updating the code mentioned over there in this link.

Comment: @iOSCuriosity ok thanks

Comment: @iOSCuriosity what happens if already have an app in appstore without these new changes?

Comment: If you compile your project with `XCode 7` (iOS 9), you will be able to receive the notifications on iOS 10 devices as well.

Comment: @atulkhatri : for me, I'm running xcode 7 iOS 9 project on an iOS 10 device, push only worked on iOS 9 devices but not 10.

Answer (score 0):

The example in Firebase docs is outdated. Here is the code for most recent Xcode 8 and Swift 3:

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        FIRApp.configure()

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_,_ in })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }
}


@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)

    }

}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
```